# Android: Make EditText empty when new value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I Want to make my `EditText` empty when you put a new value. If I use a `onClickListener` I need first to focus and then to click (Double click), if I use onFocusChangeListener it is already deleting when click another `EditText`.

**Does someone know a other way to achieve this (When first click == empty)?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you talking about hintText ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make things complicated. Simply set `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` to your `EditText`. So, when the user types-in some text and later click the text box, all the text inside will be highlighted - allowing user to type-in new text from scratch.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you for the fast answer and simple solution (+1)